# Motion - root has no access to the webcam

Tags: usb, webcam

I had an installation with motion running as webcam-server.  I reinstalled the linux-distro and reinstalled motion, and now "root" has no access to the webcam. The "pi" user still can access and work with the webcam, but the "pi" user only. Is there a way to change rights for connected webcams?   I have already reinstalled motion, and that didn't help!

Comment: Is the webcam off when root tries to access it? Or is some process being run by pi capturing a stream?

Comment: Well, when running motion under "pi" the "activity LED" of the webcam is active. When i try to access the webcam with motion under "root" the LED doesn't turn on.. so i guess that motion cannot connect to the device.. and when trying to let it run as root there's no other process that try to access the webcam too. (webcam: eyetoy > already worked 1 month ago before reinstalling the distro) >> *running with "SUDO" doesnt work, also which "real root (root)" it doesnt..

Comment: Can you find out what device is being used for the webcam in the `/dev/` directory? Does that device file have the required permissions? Look for the permission of the original device file and not any symlink that it may have.

Comment: what distro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Does your root user has a password set? If not, I'd set it a password and try again.

```
sudo passwd root
```

Comment: root and pi are both password protected.. this was one of the first things i did right after installing the linux distro

Comment: Was root added to the proper groups?  Maybe there is an issue with the device not having been put in the proper scope.